# Any idea why the component is losing partial component style when using html-to-image?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

any idea what causes the component to change its style when using html to image library?
I tried using html to canvass in that case the component lose almost 50% of its style and becomes distorted..

[image: Codesandbox Example]